# Odd Inheritence PHP issue

Tags: php

Appologies if this is a duplicate, could not seem to either search for the right words or does not exist (somehow i doubt this and likely i am making an obvious mistake).

```
<?php

class Test {
    public $var = true;

    public function test() {
        var_dump($this->var);
    }
}

class Testing extends Test {
    public $var = false;
}

$test = new Testing();
$test->test();
```

Simple enough program, base class, with a method, inheriting class with an override, then calling the base method.

Gives output, False, line return False,

What?  Why twice? Exactly my question good man.

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Thanks

Comment: may be `test` method used as `php4` constructor, because it has same name with class...

Comment: If you like, answer formally and ill thumbs up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because your method name same with class name.
Methods like this been used as a class constructor in PHP4 - [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.constructor.php)
They still works, when you have not `__construct` method for compatibility.